# Unable to get JSON param in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I faced an extremely sad issue with JSON parameters and honestly don't know how to resolve it.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, with JQuery on client side. On MVC side I have the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SearchAsync(ServerRequest request)
    {
        ....
    }

    public JsonResult SearchCompleted()
    {
        ....
    }
```

On client side, in turn, I have the following code:

```
function doSearch() {

    var page = 1;
    var startDate = $("#startdate-picker").val();
    var endDate = $("#enddate-picker").val();
    var sortingColumn = "Id";
    var type = $("#ordertype-selector").val();
    var user = $("#user-selector").val();

    var request = { Page: page, StartDate: startDate, EndDate: endDate, SortAspect: sortingColumn, OrderType: type, User: user };

    var requestToPost = JSON.stringify(request);

    $("#info-message").show();
    $("#content-table-body").hide();
    $("#page-bar").hide();

    $.post("/Common/Search",
        requestToPost,
        function (data) {
            if (data.Collection) {
                $("#info-message").hide();
                          ...
                }, 500);
            }
        }, "json");
    };
```

I have a breakpoint on SearchAsync method and when the executing is bumping on it, there is data on request. ServerRequest is marked as [Serializable] and JsonValueProviderFactory is attached to the factories collection.

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You know `public void SearchAsync` won't return any JSON back to your page, right?

Comment: 2Joey: Sure. This class is derived from AsyncController. Some sort of long-polling implementation.

Comment: 2ek_ny: I'm trying to pass some data to the parameter, but getting nothing. Bunch of default values, you know.

Comment: is your path in `$.post` correct? i think it should be `/common/SearchCompleted`

Comment: also you are sending data in your post request and in your action `SearchCompleted()` doesnot expect any value ?

Comment: 2 3nimgma: Yep, it is totally correct and SearchCompleted doesn't expect any value.

Comment: Guys, I've resolved this issue. Pretty strange, but everything works without *.stringify();

Thanks for your attention ant time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The removing of *.stringify() method solved this issue.